# vim diff does not work

Tags: vim, plugins, vimdiff

Somehow my vim (macvim) stops showing me the highlighted differences betweeen two files.

My env:

- osx 10.9 with macvim installed

Facts:

- The diff works a few months ago when I do either of below:

  - vimdiff a b, or
  - vim -d a b

It shows the color diff

Now, it does not show the color diff, it loads two files to the buff,

- either showing the same file(a vs a) in the vsplit windows (a few weeks ago)
- or showing two files (a vs b) in the vsplit windows (current)

then I will have to use :diffThis for both windows to see diff in color

Diagnosis:

I used: vim -d a b -u None to disable all plugins, it shows color diff, I though it's one of the plugins causing issues, then I tried disable one by one(move the plugin out of directory), but even I disabled all plugins I still can not see diff in color.

I have spent a few days on this but no luck.

Please if anyone knows how to resolve it.

Comment: What’s in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: lots of stuff, what particularly could be the concern?

Comment: You tell me. `-u None` disables your `.vimrc`, and it works using that, so…. You could also check by binary search; delete half of it (making sure the syntax is still valid after doing so), if it works, repeat on half of the other half, if not, repeat on half of that half.

Comment: Thanks very much, I did a try to move out the vimrc file and it works. something there inside the vimrc interfered with the diff stuff. I will update again.

Comment: @minitech `vim -u NONE` also disables plugins. Most likely the problem is with your colorscheme.

Comment: @FDinoff: stephencheng mentioned disabling all plugins. (And, of course, plugins are not a real thing.)

Comment: @stephencheng Is your disk full? Use df command to get more info on the partition space. I faced similar issues with vimdiff, it was resolved by disk cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Find the guilt:

"au VimEnter * nested silent! exe "argdo e" | bn

This was for a plugin to load multiple files into buffer

Thanks for all your help.